# Overpass API over remote PostgreSQL

Tags: overpass-api

Is there a way to setup overpass API over a remote PostgreSQL + Postgis setup ? like the ones we can setup using osmosis+osm2psql setup ?

Currently I have setup overpass-api over DB directory using --db-dir option. But I want to use remote PostgreSQL DB, so that I can scale up overpass-api

Answer (score 1):

Overpass API uses a custom file based format. You cannot use Postgresql as a backend.